# How can I get details of single field in mongo db

Tags: mongodb

I am making a web app. Currently I am storing the messages inside messages columns like below.

[image]

I have a column called msges and I have messages as time as key and value details. I want to create a function in which I pass the time, It will return the details of it. Can anyone help me? I can get single field but I don't know how to get it through key value. This is my function.

```
function getMessageDetails(uname,time,callback){
  global.users.find({"uname" : uname,"msges":time},
  // {"friends.friendUname":1,_id:0},
  {_id:0},
  function(err,doc){
    if(err){
      callback(false,err,"Message not found.",null);
    }else{
      callback(true,null,"",doc);
    }
  }
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally try to model your data a bit diffrently, If you had:

```
{
   _id: "123123",
   //...
   friends: [
      { friendName: "etc..."}
   ],
   msges : [
       {
           time: "16:25:02",
           from: "alizia",
           title : "hi buddy",
           read: true
       },
       {
           time: "12:25:02",
           from: "bob",
           title : "hi bobby",
           read: false
       }
   ]
}
```

You'd be able to query the following data by:

```
db.users.find({_id: "123123", "msges.time" : "16:25:02"}, { "msges.$.from" : 1 })
```

and will just pull out the one msg based on the query:

```
{
        "_id" : "123123",
        "msges" : [
                {
                        "time" : "16:25:02",
                        "from" : "alizia",
                        "title" : "hi buddy",
                        "read" : true
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am now trying to do it this way. Can you also tell me a function for how to delete it as well?

Comment: You'd have to do an update with a `$pull` and condition (same as the query above) see - https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/update/pull/